# How to send the file details to be sent in tcp flex to flex?

Tags: apache-flex, file, air

I am trying to send the file details one air app to anther air application using tcp. Can anybody help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.onlytechtalks.com/techtalks/2010/05/belugafile-%E2%80%93-adobe-air-app-to-share-large-files-directly-btw-two-computers/

Comment: Hi Vinothbabu, thanks for answering but the link u gave is not my solution. I am implementing an application of file sharing. So before sending the file, I want to send the file details(file name,size,type,..etc) in the form of object using TCP and at receiver end the another air should receive it as an object. Actually my server is of cpp. Any one can help in how to send object in flex and how to receive it in Flex air or CPP using TCP.